# A general result on scattering off a potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-equation

Consider $V_1$, $V_2$ real potentials, $V1(x) \leq V_2(x) \leq 0$ for all x. $V_i(x) =0$ for $|x|>a$ . A particle obeying 1D shrodinger is input from left to each potential. Is it possible that probability of reflection from $V_1$ > probability reflection from $V_2$. Give proof or counterexample.

I’ve considered box potentials of varying width but the algebra is horrendous, I’m pretty sure this is a counterexample. Is there a nice way?

Comment: I can't find the formula for reflection coefficient for rectangular potential well online. However, if you look at corresponding result for [rectangular pontential barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_potential_barrier#E_%3E_V0),  you will find for suitable energy $E$, perfect transmission (i.e. zero reflection) is possible. Just pick a $V_2(x)$ which is  reflectionless for the incoming energy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula  achille hui mentions is on this OpenLearn page on [Scattering from finite square wells and barriers](http://www.open.edu/openlearn/science-maths-technology/science/physics-and-astronomy/scattering-and-tunnelling/content-section-3.5)

[image]

The transmission coefficient is $1$ for for depth $V=V_0$ and some values of $E$, so the reflection coefficient $R$ is $0$. For a different $V=V_1$ the zeros of $R$ will be displaced. Thus, you can find values of $E$ for which $R=0$ for $V_0$ but not $V_1$ or vice versa.